# como deixar o slide responsivo

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

gente estou com esse slide tentando deixar ele responsivo só que ele ta cobrindo umas coisas que vem logo abaixo do slide(estou fechando a tag no local certo), e a imagem quando diminuo fica mostrando toda certinha mais quando eu deixo o tamanho normal fica horrivel. me ajudem .
já agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda ! <3

```css
* {margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-weight: 300;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
.inner-wrapper {
    
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider-wrapper {
max-height: 60em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    position: relative;

}

#s1 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s2 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s3 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s4 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s1:hover,
#s2:hover,
#s3:hover,
#s4:hover {
  opacity: .50;
}



.control {
  display: none;
}

#Slide1:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#Slide2:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#Slide3:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#Slide4:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#Slide1:checked + #s1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide2:checked + #s2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide3:checked + #s3 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide4:checked + #s4 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overflow-wrapper {
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <div id="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <input checked type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide1" />
            <label for="Slide1" id="s1"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide2" />
            <label for="Slide2" id="s2"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide3" />
            <label for="Slide3" id="s3"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide4" />
            <label for="Slide4" id="s4"></label>
            <div class="overflow-wrapper">
                <a class="slide"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/gamelogia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/gamer.jpg?resize=1280%2C640&ssl=1" /></a>
                <a class="slide"><img src="https://compass-ssl.xbox.com/assets/dc/48/dc486960-701e-421b-b145-70d04f3b85be.jpg?n=Game-Hub_Content-Placement-0_New-Releases-No-Copy_740x417_02.jpg" /></a>
                <a class="slide" ><img src="https://blog.sympla.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Como-organizar-um-campeonato-de-v%C3%ADdeo-game-Capa.png" /></a>
                <a class="slide"><img src="http://noticias.universia.com.br/net/images/cultura/e/ev/eve/evento-sao-paulo-relacao-games-artes-noticias.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente seu problema é que a classe `.inner-wrapper` está com `position:absolute`, ai ela sai do fluxo de conteúdo e o que vem abaixo fica encoberto pelas imagens... Não tem nada a ver com FlexBox e menos ainda com Bootstrap!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja

```css
* {margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-weight: 300;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
.inner-wrapper {

  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider-wrapper {
max-height: 60em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    position: relative;

}

#s1 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s2 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s3 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s4 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s1:hover,
#s2:hover,
#s3:hover,
#s4:hover {
  opacity: .50;
}



.control {
  display: none;
}

#Slide1:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#Slide2:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#Slide3:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#Slide4:checked ~ .overflow-wrapper {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#Slide1:checked + #s1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide2:checked + #s2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide3:checked + #s3 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Slide4:checked + #s4 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overflow-wrapper {
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <input checked type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide1" />
        <label for="Slide1" id="s1"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide2" />
        <label for="Slide2" id="s2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide3" />
        <label for="Slide3" id="s3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="slide" class="control" id="Slide4" />
        <label for="Slide4" id="s4"></label>
        <div class="overflow-wrapper">
            <a class="slide"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/gamelogia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/gamer.jpg?resize=1280%2C640&ssl=1" /></a>
            <a class="slide"><img src="https://compass-ssl.xbox.com/assets/dc/48/dc486960-701e-421b-b145-70d04f3b85be.jpg?n=Game-Hub_Content-Placement-0_New-Releases-No-Copy_740x417_02.jpg" /></a>
            <a class="slide" ><img src="https://blog.sympla.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Como-organizar-um-campeonato-de-v%C3%ADdeo-game-Capa.png" /></a>
            <a class="slide"><img src="http://noticias.universia.com.br/net/images/cultura/e/ev/eve/evento-sao-paulo-relacao-games-artes-noticias.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores voluptate placeat, ad fugiat modi dignissimos nulla id repellat odit ipsa tenetur incidunt aspernatur veritatis fugit unde perspiciatis sunt error inventore necessitatibus pariatur! Laborum sit eligendi esse odio eos temporibus perferendis laboriosam non sunt atque facere expedita aperiam, deleniti quis! Reprehenderit ipsam dolor amet asperiores, eveniet cupiditate obcaecati incidunt nobis nam neque quae unde eaque, recusandae, perspiciatis quo temporibnsequuntur? Incidunt cumque rerum iste!
</p>
```

Comment: Hugo, como que você testa a renderização dessa maneira no navegador? talvez esse não é o lugar correto de perguntar isso mas não sei onde perguntar alem daqui.

Comment: @Renan no Chrome aperta f12, ai ao lado da setinha de inspecionar tem um ícone que quando vc clica nele habilita essa janela responsiva com esse resize etc

Comment: Vlw, consegui fazer.

Comment: cara você é um Deus !!  TE AMO <3

Comment: @caiquesey massa 

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Qdo vc diz "umas coisas" vc quer dizer os bullets de navegação do slider? Se for, a posição dos bullets está presa pelo bottom 25px; Sugiro que vc posicione verticalmente usando top em vez de bottom, e para ficar responsivo, use unidades vw.

```
#s1,#s2,#s3,#s4 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:60vw;
  margin-left: -36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

#s2 {
  margin-left: -12px;
}

#s3 {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

#s4 {
  margin-left: 36px;
}
```

Para a altura do inner-wrapper, sugiro usar tbm vw

```
.inner-wrapper {

  width: 100%;
  height: 90vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Resultado: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOLXgZ